# Open Sheet on TabBar Item Click in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swiftui, tabs

My Code is:

```
struct TabsBaseView: View {
    @State private var selection: TabItems = .first
    @State private var visibility: TabBarVisibility = .visible
    
    var body: some View {
        TabBar(selection: $selection, visibility: $visibility) {
            HomeTabView()
                .tabItem(for: TabItems.first)
            SearchTabView()
                .tabItem(for: TabItems.second)
            Text("Add")
                .tabItem(for: TabItems.third)
            NotificationsTabView()
                .tabItem(for: TabItems.fourth)
            MenuView()
                .tabItem(for: TabItems.fifth)
        }
    }
}
```

menu is a more button, I want to present a sheet instead a view on click of menu, but this sheet should be overlay on previous opened view.

This could be achieve for iPhone by using like this:

```
Color.Gray
   .tabItem(for: TabItems.fifth)
```

but when we open it on iPad all the background will be Gray that looks very odd, I want to present it on existing opened View.

Comment: So you are only asking for solution on iPad because it works on iPhone?

Comment: No , in iPhone still we are giving view to this tab either this is clear colour, i want to open a sheet on existing view on click tab item

Comment: Where did you get TabBar from ?